# Firefox / Mac still scrolling page when disabled with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am searching for a solution to disable the scroll on a horizontal slider so that I can control the scroll myself and then have the slider snap to a position after going so far of a distance. This feature is mainly for touch devices, but would also be handy for trackball/"mouse wheel" devices.
I came across this post here: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily).

I am using Firefox 22, Mac OSX 10.8.4, and have a mouse that has trackball like functionality without the ball, similar to a touch screen)
If I go to the demo page from the post above (http://jsbin.com/disable-scrolling), it does not work in Firefox but works in Chrome 28.0.1500.95 and Safari 6.0.5.

I cannot figure out what is going on.
Is there another Firefox specific event that is being triggered after the scroll is finished to create the effect of momentum in the slide/scroll/swipe movement?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this ["Swiper" plugin](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) and in the [code](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/dist/idangerous.swiper-2.0.js) on line 1010, found why it was not working.

Firefox needs the extra event listener of 'wheel'.

`window.addEventListener('wheel', wheel, false);`